# can not connect my app to web service

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, execute

can not work my android app when connect web service and can not connect to web service

```
     public class Rgister extends Activity {
        private Spinner spinner1, spinner2, spinner3, spinner4;
            public  static String res="";
            private Button mButton;
            static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            static Random rnd = new Random();

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.register);
                ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_2);
                v.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_);
                new GetData("","feri").execute();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and GetData class:

```
class GetData extends AsyncTask {


    private String Link = "";

    private String User = "";

    public GetData(String link, String user) {

        Link = link;
        User = user;

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        try {
            String data= URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(User,"UTF8");
            URL mylink = new URL(Link);
            URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();


            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append("line");


            }
            Rgister.res=sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return "";


    }
}
```